# Can someone explain to me how this code works?(Program to ask for user input again if a numeric value expected and the user enters some other input)

Tags: c++

I was reading a book on c++ (c++ primer plus) and found this code.

The purpose of the program is that if a numeric input is expected from the user to read it to ,say an array->

1)Reset cin to new input
2)Get rid of the bad input
3)Prompt the user to try again  (exact words of the book)

Here is the code->(exact code copied from the book)

```
#include <iostream>
const int Max=5;
int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    //get data
    int golf[Max];
    cout<<"please enter your golf scores.\n";
    cout<<"you must enter "<<Max<<" rounds.\n";
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<Max;i++) {
        cout<<"round #"<<i+1<<": ";
        while(!(cin>>golf[i])) {
            cin.clear();
            while(cin.get()!='\n')
                continue;
            cout<<"PLease enter a number: ";
         }
    }
    double total=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<Max;i++)
        total+=golf[i];

    cout<<total/Max<<" = average score "<<Max<<" rounds\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The particular part which i don't understand is:

```
cin.clear();
while(cin.get()!='\n')
continue;
```

I'm a little unclear about the function of `cin.clear()` , the need of `continue` here , and what the while test conidtion does and how does it work.

A test run->

(italic part is the user input)

**Please enter your golf scores.**
**You must enter 5 rounds**.
**round #1:** *88*
**round #2:** *87*
**round #3:** *duh*
**Please enter a number:** *103*
**round #4:** *94*
**round #5:** *86*
**91.6 = average score 5 rounds**

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!(cin>>golf[i]))

 {

    cin.clear();
    while(cin.get()!='\n')
        continue;


    cout<<"PLease enter a number: ";

 }
```

First let's example the while condition. It seems to check if the value of the expression (`cin >> golf[i]`) is false. The falue of `cin >> golf[i]` is `cin` itself. So how can it be false? If a >> operation fails for the input stream, a flag named fail is set. That's what operator ! checks. So the condition means while after trying to read a number the object cin has fail set, do...

Now, once the fail flag is set, there isn't much you can do with an input stream. You won't be able to continue reading data from the stream unless you reset the fail flag. That's what `cin.clear()` does.

Then it munches the rest of the bad input line (which was NOT consumed since >> failed) by reading character by character until reaching the end of line.

And finally it prompts the user for new input.

Answer (score 0):

Since `golf[i]` is an `int`, `cin>>golf[i]` will return `true` (or a value interpreted as `true` in earlier versions of C++ Standard Library) when the input is an `int`. Hence, `while(!(cin>>golf[i]))` will repeat until `true` is returned.

Inside the `while` loop you find code that ignores all input until a `\n` with the loop that stops only after receiving `'\n'` input:

```
while(cin.get()!='\n')
    continue;
```

It also clears the flag indicating that `cin` is in a failure state by calling `clear()`.

**Note:** This code makes an assumption that `cin` never ends, which makes it unsafe. If the input is taken from a file with invalid data, this program will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: what is especially don't get is `while(cin.get()!='n')` this part. Can you please explain it in more detail

Comment: @Utkarsh `cin.get()` returns the next character. `'\n'` (note the backslash!) stands for the end-of-line character. The loop continues looping until the next character read from the input is the end-of-line marker, at which point the nested loop exits, and the outer loop is allowed to restart.

Comment: Why is it important to read till `'\n'` . Can't we just clear the buffer so allow further user input? or have i misunderstood the purpose

Comment: @Utkarsh You can't clear the buffer, because there may be more stuff buffered at the time you want to clear it. This can happen, for example, when you read from a file. That's why the author decided to read and discard one character at a time.